# Can I add a submenu to a md-tooltip?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tooltip, angular-material

I have my md-tooltip for a sidebar but I want to be able to click on it and have a submenu option. For example if in my Profile menu there is a submenu Contacts I would like to be able to access the Contacts when I hove over the Menu Icon, I see my tooltip on the right side then go to it, it stays and does not disappears immediately and then have a link into the tooltip.

```
</ul>
  <md-tooltip class="navbar-tooltip" md-direction="right">
    <div>
      <span translate="{{route.label}}"></span>
    </div>
  </md-tooltip>
</li>
```

It looks like this so far. My question is, is it even possible when using Angular?

Comment: Tooltip is just for showing tip or hints. For menus check this https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/menuBar

Comment: But I want my menu to look like a tooltip, i mean when you hover over an icon or a button it shows without clicking.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add md-menu-bar and invoke the `$mdOpenMenu($event)` on `on-mouseover` event.

Check this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8vwk069d/1/)

Your target behaviour using the below function

```
<md-button ng-mouseover="$mdOpenMenu($event)">
```

For Detailed options checkout the [Demo](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/menuBar) and [Docs](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdMenuBar) for `md-menu-bar`

Hope this Helps !

Comment: I already did it by using the ng-if directive and adding more div's to the structure

Comment: But this is also very useful for a next occasion